# What does "years of [someone]" mean and how can it be used?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, subjects

> Years of him swearing that he would never end up like his father and he was beginning to become more like him little by little.

In the sentence above, is "years of him" the subject?

Then, can I use these like "years of me", "years of her", "years of someone or something" as a subject in the context?

And what does it mean "years of him" in the context?

Answer (score 1):

That's a time expression about "years of swearing", like "hours of rainfall," or "weeks of hard work".  He's saying `(In spite of/Despite/Even after) years of (him) swearing he would never end up like his father, he was becoming more like him.`

Here's an answer on the English Language stackexchange about gerund phrases with subjects ("him swearing..."):  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner